# Spark OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on Simple S3 List Code

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have an S3 bucket of 15million tiny files. The files have the same prefix and a UUID suffix. In an attempt to parallelize the list needed to read the files into an RDD, I'm creating a set of the ~1260 possible first two letters and sending a separate list request for each. However, in trying to generate the RDD of a list of keys, I run into the classic OutofMemory Error. Here's the code, which seems relatively simple - why am I running into these errors?

```
#Create prefixes:
import string, itertools
prefix_chars=range(0,10)+list(string.ascii_lowercase)
prefixes=[]
for i in itertools.permutations(prefix_chars, 2): 
    prefix=''
    for x in i: prefix=prefix+str(x)
    prefixes.append(prefix)

def listBucket(bucket_name, file_prefix):
    import boto
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    keylist=[]
    for i in bucket.list(file_prefix): keylist.append(i)
    return keylist

getKeys=sc.parallelize(prefixes).repartition(len(prefixes)).flatMap(lambda x: listBucket(bucket,file_prefix)).collect()
```

I'm starting spark with the following conf:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
         .set("spark.executor.instances",50)
         .set("spark.executor.cores",10)
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "22g")
         .set("spark.akka.frameSize","100")
         .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","24g")
         .set("spark.driver.memory","40g"))

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

I'm running on EMR, Spark version 1.3 (for bootstrap dependencies, I had to use an older version of EMR and Spark).

Comment: As a start, you have `lambda x: listBucket(bucket,file_prefix)` in your flatMap statement, but neither bucket or file_prefix are defined in the code you gave. Assuming bucket is defined, should the function be `lambda x: listBucket(bucket, x)`?

Comment: A second question, is it necessary to use collect?

Comment: bucket and file_prefix are entered earlier in the script, but they can be any bucket and any file prefix.

Comment: I tried this without the collect() as well, and run into the same issue when this stage executes.

Comment: Not sure where your OOM error happened but presumably in `listBucket`. Maybe try to `return bucket.list(file_prefix)` instead of keeping a local list?

Comment: @econgineer any chance you figured by yourself what went wrong? If so, please provide an answer here.